# Ruby command to edit a field in a SAM file

Tags: ruby, shell, bioinformatics

Inspired by a [bioinformatics question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55938014/1968), I wanted to brush up on my Ruby knowledge, since I’ve been meaning to replace my command-line use of Perl by Ruby.

Briefly, the problem description is as follows:

> Given is a SAM file. This is a whitespace-delimited file with at least 11 columns. After the 11th column, there can be further optional columns in a specific format<sup>1</sup>. If there is an optional column starting with `RX:Z:` then remove all dashes in that column.

Here’s my Ruby “one-liner”:

```bsh
ruby -ane '
  $F[11..].grep(/^RX:Z:/).map! {|x| x.gsub!(/-/, "")}
  puts $F.join("\t")
' file.sam
```

This works but I’m wondering if there’s a way of making this more idiomatic and/or more concise. For instance, I’m puzzled by the apparent necessity to manually join the modified `$F` back together. There doesn’t seem to be a way of using the `-p` flag instead of `-n`, and getting the in-place changes to `$F` to propagate to `$_`. `perl -ae` has the same limitation as far as I know.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This isn’t relevant to the question but each optional column is roughly described by the regular expression `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]:[AifZHB]:\S*`. The actual description is more complicated (for instance, if the character between the two colons is `Z` then the field after the second colon is a zero-terminated C-string of printable characters, and notably can include space).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much to say here, it is clear what your solution is doing, and attempts to make it more concise would just make it harder to read.

I recommend replacing `map!` with `each` - `map!` indicates that you want the values returned by `grep` to be changed in place. Since that result is then discarded, it makes the code more difficult to understand.

Personally, I avoid `!` methods whenever possible. The hidden mutation which can occur makes code harder to reason about. It is fine in this small example (especially once `map!` is replaced with `each`), but in a larger program it will hide bugs.

Avoiding mutation in this case makes the code a bit longer, but it has the benefit of not needing to stop and think about what has changed and if it matters. I spent several minutes trying to figure out why your code *didn't* fail when a field didn't include a `-` since `gsub!` returns `nil` when no replacements are made.

Though less concise, I prefer the following version:

```bsh
ruby -ane '
$F[11..] = $F[11..].map { |x| x.start_with?("RX:Z:") ? x.gsub(/-/, "") : x }
puts $F.join "\t"
' file.sam
```

Not automatically joining `$F` back together to create `$_` makes sense, what should ruby do if you use (or modify) `$F` but then set `$_` to something else? Setting `$_` whenever `$F` is modified would be rather confusing and bad for performance.